# Problem with Sinc[x] function and rounding

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I seem to be having some trouble with the `Sinc[x]` function, and I think it's due to rounding, but I'm not sure.

The code is below, with relevant constants:

```
b = 0.1;
a = 8.7106181548*^-18;
alpha$of$r[r_] := alpha /. FindRoot[alpha - b * alpha + (b/a) * Sin[a * alpha] ==
                                    r (1 - 2 * b),  {alpha, r (1 - 2 *b)}];

u[r_] := b * Sinc[a * alpha$of$r[r]];
Plot[b - u[r], {r, 10^9, 10^10}]
```

When we plot the function `u[r]` in the range specified, it does not seem to return a continuous curve as expected. Here's a picture of the plot:

[image: wacky-looking plot]

Could anyone offer insight as to why this happens and how I could fix it? I apologize in advance if I'm missing any information, as I'm new here. Thanks!

Comment: You are running into machine precision rounding issues here. Try the option `WorkingPrecision` or look up the function `SetPrecision` in the docs. It should give you some ideas how to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your question is not about accuracy of $\text{sinc}(x)$ function itself but with the precision of `FindRoot`. When you increase working precision of the calculations (by using `WorkingPrecision` option) then the result is smooth

```
b=1/10;
a=87106181548 10^-28;
alpha[r_]:=alpha/.FindRoot[alpha-b alpha+(b/a) Sin[a alpha]==r (1-2 b), {alpha,r (1-2 b)},
                           WorkingPrecision->20];
u[r_]:=b Sinc[a alpha[r]];
Plot[b-u[r],{r,10^9,10^10}]//Quiet
```

[image]

Please note that I also increased precision of the `a` and `b` parameters by removing the decimal point.